# Static allocation in C language

Tags: c, arrays, allocation

I have the following code:

```
void main ( ) 
{
    int s;
    scanf("%i",&s);
    int a[s];
}
```

When I try to compile this code, I haven't any errors in it!! The question is can I allocate a static array with variable size?? Where this allocation is implemented(In stack or heap)??

Thanks.

Comment: Read about [`VLA`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Comment: You can in C99 and later.

Comment: C99 introduces variable lenght local arrays as a more correct way of allocating space on stack. It shall replace usage of `alloca`.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun :I tried to compile it with C90 and no problem in that!!!

Answer (score 2):

It's a variable length array. Variable length array is feature that has been introduced by c99 standard. A variable length array can only be declared at block scope and it has automatic storage duration (it cannot be declared with `static` or `extern` specifier).

Answer (score 1):

This is a C99 thing, though supported as an extension by some compilers.  Read about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array - GCC allocates them on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Per ANSI C (C89), it is not legal for arrays to have variable length.

In such cases, you are required to dynamically allocate memory from the **heap**.

```
int *a = (int*) malloc(s * sizeof(int));
```

When it's the case where you know the value of s at compile time, you can use automatic allocation as follows:

```
int a[10]; //value of s taken to be 10
```

Here, the compiler takes .care of memory allocation for the array and it's allocated from the **stack**